# jwt server side authentication with php

Tags: php, angularjs, jwt

I'm using angular for the frontend and php as backend and use `JWT` to authenticate my users. My question is if I send a `JWT` token to my php server, what do I need to do to authenticate my user after I've decoded the token? Can I just take the send-in ID and say, this is the user that issued the request; or should I send some kind of auth_token which I should verify in my database? Or maybe there is something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to verify the digital signature of the JWT to make sure it has not been altered and identify the signer. If the verification is sucessful then you can trust in JWT content and use the `sub` claim (user id) to identify the sender.

JWT is the proof-of-authentication. The frontend should send the JWT in each request